# best practice using memcached with mysql search query?

Tags: mysql, memcached

i've friendship_request database table , will if this table have say a million record
when i'll try to search for requests concerning tom for example and actually there is no friendship request for tom in these million record so which is better:
to index to in memcache when some one send request to tom and then first try to check memcache for tom so if present go to database and make a search query.
OR to make a search query directly without first check memcache
which is faster?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking against Memcache *first* will be faster. Like the name applies, items are stored in memory, and will have less I/O than a database look up. However, Memcached will evict any data if the server's RAM becomes full. For this reason, it would be unwise to assume that *any* data put in Memcache will still be there. Even before the item's time has expired.

Most Memcache wrappers and API's will return FALSE, or NOT_FOUND. So your application will just need to identify if your requested items was stored, and if not, check the database. Upon completing the database search, simply record *in Memcached* the results or no results. This will prevent your application from re-running the same search again.

Here's a quick interaction with Memcached

```sh
shell ~> telnet localhost 11211
tel ~> get tom
       NOT_FOUND

tel ~> set tom 0 86400 5
    ~> 1,2,3
       STORED

tel ~> get tom
       VALUE tom 0 5
       1,2,3
       END
```

And a quick little PHP class example

```
<?php
class FriendshipRequest extends Memcache {

    const KEY_PREFIX = 'fr_' ; // Use constant prefix to create namespace
    const FLAG = 0;            // Flag for memechache storage option
    const EXPIRE = 86400;      // Store for one day

    public function __construct() {
    $this->addServer('localhost',11211);
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Find a name
     *
     * First check memcached. If not found,
     * search database, and store results
     * in a JSON string
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return array
     */
    public function find($name) {
            $key = $this->toKey($name);
            $results = $this->get($key);
            if( $results === false ) {
                    $results = $this->databaseSearch($name);
                    $this->set($key,json_encode($results),self::FLAG,self::EXPIRE);
            } else {
                    $results = json_decode($results);
            }
            return $results;
    }

    /**
     * Run a database search, and return array of matching ID's
     * @param string $name
     * @return array
     */
    private function databaseSearch($name) {
            $sql = sprintf('SELECT `friend_id` FROM `friendship_request` WHERE `friend_name` LIKE "%s"', mysql_real_escape_string($name));
            $matches = array();
            // Database connection omitted
            $results = mysql_query($sql);
            while( $row = mysql_fetch_object($results) ) {
             array_push($matches,$results->friend_id);
            }
            mysql_free_result($results);
            return $matches;
    }

    /**
     * Create a namespace for key
     * @param string $name
     * @return string
     */
    private function toKey($name) {
            return self::KEY_PREFIX.sha1($name);
    }
}
```